# Get dynamic Form Value from Django Forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to get the `totalPrice` value from the changing value of the form field through JavaScript.

My view part:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        if (not closed):
            form = BookingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                booking = form.save(commit=False)
                booking.author = user
                booking.hotelName = hotel.name
                booking.save()
                success = "Success!"
            else:
                return render(request, "hotels/hotel.html", {
                    "form": form
                })
        messages.info(request, success)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("hotel", args=(hotel.id,)))
    else:
        return render(request, "hotels/hotel.html", {
            "hotel": hotel,
            "closed": closed,
            "message": message,
            "form": BookingForm()
        })
```

My HTML + JS Code:

```
{% if not closed %}
<div class="container login">
    <h2>Book Now!</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="Book">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endif %}

<script>
    let price = 0;

    const check = (id) => {
        if(document.querySelector(`#${id}`).checked) {
            price += 300;
            document.querySelector('#totalPrice').value = `${price}`;
        }
        if(!document.querySelector(`#${id}`).checked) {
            if (!price <= 0) {
                price -= 300;
                document.querySelector('#totalPrice').value = `${price}`;
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelector("#breakfast").addEventListener('click', () => check("breakfast"));
        document.querySelector("#dinner").addEventListener('click', () => check("dinner"));
    })
</script>
```

And, my form (through ModelForm):

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['includeBreakfast', 'includeDinner', 'totalPrice']
        labels = {
            'includeBreakfast': 'Include Breakfast',
            'includeDinner': 'Include Dinner',
            'totalPrice': 'Total Price (in USD)'
        }

    #Visual stuff
```

the `totalPrice` is a `FloatField` in the Model, but When I try to retrieve this value from the POST, it results `None`, but I want it to take the dynamically changing value.

Comment: Your js code working or not ?

Comment: Not really, it gave an Error, but I found the solution. More info on the first answer comments

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer regarding `${price}` was incorrect.

If your javascript is correctly updating the `totalPrice` field, you might need to use the "Network" tab in your browser developer tools to confirm that this value is being POSTed.

Comment: Is the javascript correctly updating the `totalPrice` input? When you submit the form, is it validating? If it is, a Booking will be created. If not, an error will be returned. If there is an error, what is it?

Comment: When I submit the form, totalPrice comes as 0.00 in the admin page

Comment: Hello, an update. The problem was with the fact that I disabled the input field of the totalPrice field. And that seemed make the dynamically changing value to not be submitted. I changed it to 'readonly'. That was just dumb from me, Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the widget of `totalPrice` field. Before it was this:

```
self.fields['totalPrice'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'totalPrice',
            'disabled': True, #<-- The issue
            'class': 'form-control',
        })
```

I was supposed to set a `readonly`, not a `disabled`. Now it works.

After:

```
self.fields['totalPrice'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'totalPrice',
            'readonly': 'readonly',
            'class': 'form-control',
        })
```